# adding and subtracting in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in Visual Basic 2010 Express and I need to make a basic program where you enter numbers into `textbox1`, and the numbers are added or subtracted from `textbox2` using either an add or subtract button. My problem is only one number gets added or subtracted. e.g if I add 50, it only displays 50, I can't just keep adding to get 50, 100 etc.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Subtract.Click
        Dim number1, number2 As Integer 
        number1 = TextBox4.Text 
        number2 = txtVariables.Text 
        TextBox4.Text = number1 - number2 
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTransfer_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTransfer.Click
        Dim TextBoxContents As String
        TextBoxContents = txtVariables.Text
        TextBox4.Text = TextBoxContents
        If Val(TextBox4.Text) > 1 Then
            TextBoxContents = Val(TextBox4.Text) + Val(txtVariables.Text)
        Else
            TextBox4.Text = TextBoxContents
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You could really make your code a lot easier to read by giving your Textboxes, Buttons, and other controls more sensible names.  You will thank yourself later.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this is really only the first program I've ever made so I don't really know much of what i'm doing

Comment: Also look at turning **Option Strict On**. It will help with coding. Since you're new and your program is in its early stages it would be good to do this and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Public Class Form1 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Subtract.Click
Dim number1, number2 As Integer 
number1 = Convert.toInt32(TextBox4.Text) 
number2 = Convert.toInt32(txtVariables.Text)
TextBox4.Text = (number1 - number2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks, now how do I get it to add? And i'm required to not let the number drop under 0, how can I do that?

Comment: Use `+` instead of `-` in the event handler for the "Add" button. You can prevent the number from going below 0 by checking the result with an `If` statement, and if it is < 0, don't update the number.

Comment: When I run the program and click 'Add' it just crashes and says errors, what should I do? Only the subtract one works.

Comment: You should be using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead in case the TextBox contains non-convertible text.